# File Upload in Firefox JSF1.2

Tags: file, upload, jsf-1.2

File upload shows only the file name. Is there a way where we can get the full path of the uploaded file?

```
**JSP**
 <h:outputText>
 <input name="uploadFile" title="Upload File" type="file" size="50" 
                        accept="*.csv;*.txt" />
</h:outputText>

**PagenBean**

String filePath = (String)super.getRequestMap().get("uploadFile");
```

When i upload the file, i get only the file name in pagebean. But i need the complete path of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

No, Due to the security reasons. You will not be able to get the full path.

End user directory structure will not be shown.